# Como somar a quantidade de registros em que o penúltimo registro entra no Where?

Tags: mysql, query

Preciso de uma *query*, em *MYSQL*, em que verifique o penúltimo registro e que este registro seja igual a um determinado valor, e que conte a quantidade de registros encontrados.

Ex: penúltimo registro é do João. Preciso contar a quantidade de vezes em que João aparece como penúltimo registro.

Tentei da seguinte maneira, colocando um *group by*, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chamado AS chmd
INNER JOIN complemento AS comp ON (comp.num_chamado = chmd.num_chamado)
WHERE comp.nome like 'joao%'
GROUP BY comp.num_chamado
ORDER BY comp.id_complemento DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: id_complemento é sequencial ?

Comment: sim, é sequencial

Comment: Thiago, resolveu seu problema? marque alguma das respostas por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode obter o resultado desejado calculando a posição do registro `JOÃO` na tabela filha.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM chamado chmd
       INNER JOIN (SELECT @row_number := CASE
                                           WHEN @num_chamado = comp.num_chamado THEN @row_number + 1
                                           ELSE 1
                                         END AS row_number,
                          @num_chamado := comp.num_chamado as num_chamado,
                          comp.id_complemento,
                          comp.nome
                     FROM complemento comp
                    ORDER BY comp.num_chamado, comp.id_complemento DESC) x ON x.num_chamado = chmd.num_chamado
 WHERE x.nome LIKE 'JOÃO%'
   AND x.row_number = 2
```

---

- Realizado um `JOIN` com uma `subquery` que deve retornar os registros de complemento com sua respectiva posição;
- Utilizamos a variável `@row_number` que será reiniciada (com valor 1) sempre que o número do chamado atual (`comp.num_chamado`) for diferente do chamado anterior `@num_chamado`. Caso contrário a variável será incrementada;
- Atribuímos o número do chamado da linha atual à variável;
- O `ORDER BY` é realizado primeiramente pelo número do chamado, garantindo que não haja retornos ao mesmo código caso já tenha passado para o próximo. Logo após é realizada a ordenação pelo código do complemento decrescente (`DESC`) garantindo que o último código obterá `row_number` 1 e o penúltimo 2;
- Com o resultado filtramos com o `LIKE` os nomes que iniciam com `JOÃO` e os registros que possuem `row_number` igual a 2, ou seja, são o segundo registro considerando o `id_complemento` de trás para frente;
- Utilizamos o `COUNT` para verificar a quantidade de registros que atendem a essas condições.

---

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c956d/8).

Referência: [**MySQL row_number, This Is How You Emulate It**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Answer (score 1):

Sem a estrutura das tabelas fica um pouco complicado, mas tente assim:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(distinct chmd.num_chamado) 
FROM chamado AS chmd
INNER JOIN complemento AS comp ON comp.num_chamado = chmd.num_chamado 
                               AND comp.id_complemento = 
                                 (select 
                                      max(x.id_complemento) 
                                  from complemento x 
                                  where x.num_chamado = chmd.num_chamado 
                                  and x.id_complemento < 
                                     (select 
                                          max(y.id_complemento) 
                                      from complemento y 
                                      where y.num_chamado = x.num_chamado))
WHERE comp.nome like 'joao%'
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo auxílio. Tentei rodar, mas a query fica como se fosse em looping, e não retorna nada.

Comment: Consegue colocar a estrutura das tabelas, e dados de exemplo?

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro consegue atualizar a questão ? editei colocando uma clausula a mais no join, veja se altera algo

Comment: Dá uma olhada no `Fiddler` que eu coloquei na minha resposta. Com aqueles dados já dá pra testar sua `query`.

Comment: @Sorack vlw, testei e também funciona. Não entendi o porque ele não conseguiu

Comment: Na real eu fiz o teste aqui e deveriam aparecer duas linhas, só que apareceu só uma com a sua `query`... Dá uma olhadinha nisso que tá quase certo

Comment: eu executei um count...então só vem uma linha mesmo, com a quantidade de registros... 2... não ?

Comment: Verdade, vi isso agora. Tá certo mesmo

Comment: vlww abraços =]